# XAML Converter in different namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, namespaces, windows-phone-8.1, converters

I'm developing a c# Windows Phone 8.1 App in VC2013 and stumbled over an odd issue.

To make my Code more 'clean', I decided to put different parts of my App into different folders. There is no problem with calling XAML pages from these folders in the c# code.

**BUT** I seem to have issues linking these folders in XAML Code itself. For example I have following structure:

```
root, Files: App.cs+xaml, Mainpage.cs+xaml
|
-- Folder: Login
     |
     -- Files: LoginPage.cs+xaml
-- Folder: Converters
     |
     -- Files: converterClass.cs
```

To use the `IValueConverter` from the `converterClass.cs` like I always did, I put the following in the Header of my XAML file:

```
<Page
 x:Class="myApp.Login.LoginPage"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:local="using:meinStundenplaner.Login"
 xmlns:myConverter="using:myApp.Converters"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
 Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/standardStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <myConverter:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeConverter" />
        ... some more converters

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
...
```

Now it happens, that if I type `<myConverter:` the autocomplete does find my converter classes like usually, but when compiling (it is compiling) and testing on device none of the converters works and also I get an error in the Error-list saying

```
The name 'DateTimeConverter' in namespace 'using:myApp.Converters' does not exist.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Double check that the DateTimeConverter class is in the myApp.Converters namespace. You may have dragged the file into the folder, but forgot to change the namespace in the C# code.

Comment: Also, check that your converter is actually called DateTimeConverter.

Comment: I'm confused. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029082/3538012) (among other references), for a Windows Phone app you should be using `clr-namespace` instead of `using` in your namespace declaration. Are you really writing a Windows Phone app? If so, why aren't you using `clr-namespace`? What happens if you do? It wouldn't surprise me if the editor doesn't know the difference between Windows Phone and Windows RT and so auto-completes just fine with the wrong declaration, even though it won't compile successfully.

Comment: OK I first tried to rename it to `clr-namespace`, but as before he then gives me an error (yes, project is WP8.1) and then the dropdown (autocorrect) when I type in the namespace it corrects it back to `using`. The namespace and converter have the right name (double checked it again)

Comment: THANK YOU Peter Duniho! I am writing a win10mobile app as UniversalApp and I needed to switch to ``using`` instead of ``clr-namespace``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow ... after using VS2015 and the same error persisted, I played a little bit around with settings and stuff.

I kept being curious, why it would compile and deploy even it triggered so many errors. The problem appeared to be inconsistent.

The solution was different than expected:

You have to set `Solution Platforms` to `x86` instead of `ARM` (which I needed to deploy on device). Luckily VS2015 has this option in a handy shortcut, what you can't say about VS2013.

Nevertheless it's solved...