# Win10 UWP App, MapControl error

Tags: xaml, mvvm, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

*** NB**  This is not a duplicate as suggested below - I have the necessary namespaces and the control works fine at runtime; however, I have the updated tools 1.1.1 installed already  **NB ***

I'm putting together an MVVM Win10 UWP app using Prism 6 / Unity using the new Win10 MapControl, see basic XAML snippet below - I'm getting a design-time error; "The TypeConverter for "Style" does not support converting from a string.":

```
<maps:MapControl Name="myMap"
    Style="Terrain">
</maps:MapControl>
```

I've Googled for hours and found nothing, My approach ties up with the MSDN documentation as well as every tutorial I can find.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net WP8.1/Win10 UWP: Namespace for MapControl not found in Visual Studio Designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534197/net-wp8-1-win10-uwp-namespace-for-mapcontrol-not-found-in-visual-studio-design)

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I have the necessary namespaces and the control works fine at runtime; however, I have the updated tools 1.1.1 installed already and the problem is there.

Comment: please show more information about `Terrain`

Comment: "Terrain" is a one of the values from the mapstyles Enum.

Comment: Shahriar - I think you're just guessing now.  "StaticResource" references other resources in the project, it's not going to solve this problem (and for completeness; yes, I did try it at your suggestion and, not surprisingly, it breaks the app)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind it using the static keyword. Something like

```
<maps:MapControl Name="myMap"
    Style="{x:Static maps:MapStyle.Terrain}">
</maps:MapControl>
```

They are both in the namespace so "maps:" prefix should work.

Or alternatively just us the [numerical literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapstyle.aspx) (which is harder to read though):

```
<maps:MapControl Name="myMap"
    Style="4">
</maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: "Static" cannot be used in a Windows Universal project