# Why is my ViewModel not found?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

Why can't VS find my file?

VS Error Image and Text:

[image]

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  **The type or namespace name 'AudioFile' could not be found** (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) reOrder C:\Users\kloud\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\reOrder\reOrder\ReorderPage.xaml.cs    27  Active

I recreated the project to see if Visual Studio was doing something I couldn't see/understand and checked extensively with code that is working(correctly finds the item and binds) to see where the differences are. I couldn't find any clues though.

edit: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Also, in previous projects VS didn't have trouble finding and binding to a model.

Full code below.

**Reorder Page**

```
<Page
    x:Class="reOrder.ReorderPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:reOrder"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:reOrder.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind AudioFiles}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:AudioItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**AudioItem Model**
    (skipped usings)

```
namespace reOrder.Models
{
    public class AudioItem
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Duration { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem even after rebuilding the solution.One workaround i did was Go to your .csproj file in file explorer and now edit  under itemgroup tag add this:

```
<Compile Include="ViewModels\AudioItemModel .cs">
  <DependentUpon>Reorder.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Save it and close it and then rebuild it and now it will detect the viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job! But do you have any clue to why this might have happened? I mean, even new projects have this issue. Also, where did you find this solution?

Comment: I myself solved it by comparing various .csproj file of other uwp apps in which it was detecting the viewmodel and then found this similarity and solved it.But since i'm just a beginner i don't know why its happening :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `using` in xaml, you use `clr-namespace:`. I can't be sure of what you named your assembly, but my guess is:

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:reOrder;assembly=reOrder"
```

Comment: The error text changes to something similar:

The name "AudioItem" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:reOrder;assembly=reOrder"  

edit: The code works fine with `using` and this type of solution worked in the past for me. I am working on a tutorial template style of code.

Comment: First, is that assembly name correct? I said it was just a guess. Second, [look at this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406038/xaml-clr-namespace-using-incompatibility), maybe you are expecting xaml to be the same in all environments?

Comment: I checked, it is reOrder, I didn't change anything in the project settings and I am on Windows 10 AU building for Windows 10. How could the syntax be a problem? I mentioned that projects before this one correctly found the type and binded to it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened after I set compile target to x64.
My view model can't be found until I reset compile to Any CPU.