# Compiling PoGo-UWP has lots of problems

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I can't figure out this compilation error in Visual Studio.

[image: this]

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:CapturePokemonPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />//here
</Page.DataContext>
```

This leads to lots of further errors.  Please help.

That's not the only error, here is another error
:

[image: error 2 in another .xaml]

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:CapturePokemonPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" /> //here
</Page.DataContext>
```

[Link to the full source code](https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP) (according to @kessan)

Comment: So what's the error it's giving?

Comment: the name "MapPokemonwraper" does not exist in the namespace "using:PokemonGo_UWP.Entiries"

Comment: if you dont know what pogo is click this https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP

Comment: Hey i think this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934781/why-is-my-viewmodel-not-found

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to build [PoGo-UWP](https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP). If so, you can follow this [Dev wiki](https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP/wiki/Dev) to add "***ApplicationKeys.cs***" first.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PokemonGo_UWP.Utils
{
    public static class ApplicationKeys
    {
        public static string MapServiceToken = "{Bing Map API key}";
        public static string HockeyAppToken = null;
        public static string[] MapBoxTokens = {};
        public static string[] MapBoxStylesLight = {};
        public static string[] MapBoxStylesDark = {};
    }
}
```

Then select "PokemonGo-UWP" as `StartUp Project` and hit `F5`, you should be able to run the app.

To refresh Visual Studio's intellisense, follow this:

1. Press Ctrl+Q in Visual Studio, type `pac man gen`
2. Ensure `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` is checked.
3. Ensure `Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio` is checked.
4. Right-click "PokemonGo-UWP" Project, and select `Clean`.
5. Right-click  "PokemonGo-UWP" Project, and select `Rebuild`.

This should be able to fix the errors like:

> The name "CapturePokemonPageViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:PokemonGo_UWP.ViewModels".